# how to enable listener for label with link in sencha touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hi i create a label with link, but how to get link click listener

my code is

```
 html:'<a href="#">My Link</a>',
 listeners:{
      tap     : function()
          {
             console.log('click');
           }
      }
```

but the listener does not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your anchor a `class` and then try to use [event delegation](https://www.sencha.com/blog/event-delegation-in-sencha-touch/) like this:

```
html:'<a class="link" href="#">My Link</a>',
listeners : {
    element  : 'element',
    delegate : 'a.link',
    tap      : function() {
        console.log('click');
    }
}
```